# After appending input field to a different container, I cannot continue typing in the text input unless I click again. It loses focus

Tags: javascript

Here's the main part of the function that I'm having trouble with. I am using this function on a text input field for the oninput="myFunction" attribute.

```
function myFunction() {
var myContainer1 = document.getElementById("newContainer");
var myContainer2 = document.getElementById("inputContainer");
myContainer1.appendChild(myContainer2);
myContainer2.style.display = "inline-block";
}
```

So what I have done here is moved my input container inside of another container. After I type my first character in the input field, the field moves to the other container, however it loses focus and I cannot continue typing unless I click the input field again.

Here's an example: 
If you go to the google homepage: https://www.google.com/

When you start typing, the search field input element moves up to the header, however you can still continue typing as if nothing happened. The caret doesn't disappear and it doesn't force you to click the field to continue typing.

My issue is, right after my input element moves, it doesn't allow me to continue typing unless I click the field again.

I'd really appreciate any help!

Comment: google doesn't do it like that, google have 2 'input' not really an input, when you press a key, the event is then passed to the other 'input' (in the top) and the other one goes invisible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it by requesting the focus to the desired element:

```
function myFunction() {
  var myContainer1 = document.getElementById("newContainer");
  var myContainer2 = document.getElementById("inputContainer");
  myContainer1.appendChild(myContainer2);
  myContainer2.style.display = "inline-block";
  myContainer2.focus();
}
```